# Running a bluepy scan script on boot on a Raspberry Pi 3b

Tags: python, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, raspbian

Good day.  I am using a Raspberry Pi 3 model B running Raspbian Stretch.  I have a Python script named bluepyscanner.py which is basically a Python 3 variation of the [bluepy scanner sample code](https://ianharvey.github.io/bluepy-doc/scanner.html#sample-code) with a small addition for a .txt log file.

```
from bluepy.btle import Scanner, DefaultDelegate

class ScanDelegate(DefaultDelegate):
    def __init__(self):
        DefaultDelegate.__init__(self)

    def handleDiscovery(self, dev, isNewDev, isNewData):
        if isNewDev:
            print("Discovered device", dev.addr)
        elif isNewData:
            print("Received new data from", dev.addr)

scanner = Scanner().withDelegate(ScanDelegate())
devices = scanner.scan(10.0)

for dev in devices:
    print("Device {} ({}), RSSI={} dB".format(dev.addr, dev.addrType, dev.rssi))
    for (adtype, desc, value) in dev.getScanData():
        print("  {} = {}".format(desc, value))
        with open('bluepyscanlog.txt', 'a') as the_file:
            the_file.write("{}={}\n".format(desc, value))
```

I can run this script perfectly when I launch it from terminal with

```
$ sudo python3 /home/pi/bluepyscanner.py
```

However, I am somehow unable to get this script to run automatically on boot.  I have tried the following three methods separately and none has worked so far:

1. rc.local (h[ttps://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/rc-local.md](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/rc-local.md)): I appended the following line to /etc/rc.local

   python3 /home/pi/bluepyscanner.py
2. Cron (https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/cron.md): I used the Cron GUI and added a recurring task to be launched "at reboot"

   sudo python3 /home/pi/bluepyscanner.py
3. systemd (https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/systemd.md): I followed the instructions on the linked documentation page with main.py replaced by my bluepyscanner.py and the working directory replaced by /home/pi

Can anyone give me a pointer on what might have gone wrong?  Bluetooth is enabled and bluepy is installed in accordance with [this](https://github.com/IanHarvey/bluepy).  I don't think the script has run because, unlike when ran from terminal, bluepyscanlog.txt was not created.

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: You can't run `python` scripts on startup ! Your application not `system component` be carefull on selecting **RUNLEVEL** !

Comment: @dsgdfg What do you mean?  I think the samples given on the Raspberry Pi official website for rc.local and systemd (see links in my original question) both involve running a Python script?

Comment: Some of your links are garbage ! Low-level users can manually change their initial configuration(`/etc/rc.local`[guide for beginners right here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/update-rc.d.8.html)). The system will automatically discard your process. Python can be a system component but it certainly cannot process the system. If a shell script is written, the python directories are passed and the application is executed. You must save this ' SH ' application to the system (`Update-RC. D runPython.sh here_some_number`)

Comment: **The system will automatically discard your process.** CPU access, RAM allocation, process tree creation, hardware access permissions, etc. `Rasperry Pi can be toy but you can't play with the kernel inside!`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make these changes into your script

```
...
 with open('/home/pi/bluepyscanlog.txt', 'a+') as the_file:
...
```

and make the proper changes in your /etc/rc.local

```
sudo python3 /home/pi/bluepyscanner.py
```

May be you can see previous copies of bluepyscanlog.txt at /
If this doesn't do the job bluetooth service may be starting after rc.local is executed. Do this modifications in your `/etc/rd.local` as `sudo`

```
....
sudo service bluetooth start
sudo python3 /home/pi/bluepyscanner.py > /home/pi/bb.log

exit 0
```

Ensure that exit 0 is the last command in the file. If you created rc.local manually ensure it gets execution rights.

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/rc.local
```

You will see that your script is being executed.
In my raspberry these are the contents of bb.log

```
Discovered device d2:xx:XX:XX:XX:XX
Device d2:xx:XX:XX:XX:XX (random), RSSI=-62 dB
  Flags = 06
  0x12 = 08001000
  Incomplete 128b Services = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  16b Service Data = xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  Complete Local Name = xxxxxxxxxxx
  Tx Power = 05
```

(Xs mask original content)

Comment: The absolute path and starting the bluetooth service first solved it for me.  Thanks.  I didn't find changing "a" to "a+" in open() necessary though.